# How to 'double' numbers in an array, and save it in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, integer

This is a 2 step problem:

1.) I am trying to 'double' the contents of one array (original Array), save it in a new array (Doubled Array).

2.) Then assign those two arrays to an Object with 2 attributes. 
New Object
Orginal Numbers
Doubled Numbers

This is what I have so far, what am I doing wrong?

```
var numbers = [8, 12, 5, 2, 5, 7];
var doubledNumbers = [];


function doubled(arr){
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
  var dub = arr[i];
   var dubb = dub*2;
   doubledNumbers.push(dubb);
 }

}

var collectionNumbers = {
  orginialNumbers: numbers,
  doubledNumbers: doubled(numbers)
};

console.log(collectionNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with your current code, is that your `doubled` function is returning nothing (which means it's returning `undefined`).

A better function would look like this:

```
function doubled (arr) {
    var doubled = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        doubled.push(arr[i] * 2);
    }
    return doubled;
}
```

However, an even better solution would be to just do this:

```
var collectionNumbers = {
    orginialNumbers: numbers,
    doubledNumbers: numbers.map(function (n) { return n * 2; })
};
```

`.map` is awesome.

Comment: Thanks!  Very through, thank your for suggesting a "simple" method and then the more advanced method!!

Answer (score 9):

The best way to do this in Javascript is using the `map` function:

```
var doubledNumbers = numbers.map(n => n*2);
```

The argument to `map` is the function that it uses to transform the elements in the first array into the elements in the second array. It is a tremendously useful method.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your original question, the reason you were seeing undefined in `collectionNumbers` is because you forgot to return doubledNumbers in your function (and functions by default return `undefined`.

```
var numbers = [8, 12, 5, 2, 5, 7];
var doubledNumbers = [];


function doubled(arr){
 var doubledNumbers = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
  var dub = arr[i];
   var dubb = dub*2;
   doubledNumbers.push(dubb);
 }
 return doubledNumbers;

}

var collectionNumbers = {
  orginialNumbers: numbers,
  doubledNumbers: doubled(numbers)
};

console.log(collectionNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole routine can be simplified to

```
var numbers = [8, 12, 5, 2, 5, 7];
var collectionNumbers = {
  orginialNumbers: numbers,
  doubledNumbers: numbers.map(function(n) { return n*2; })
};

console.log(collectionNumbers);
```

using Array.map to create a new array with the doubled numbers

Answer (score 0):

using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), you can double and return new array

```js
 let inputArray = [9,8,7,3,2]
 let outputArray = Array.from(inputArray, x => x *2) // creates new array
 console.log(outputArray)
```